# Pygame image dimensions?

Tags: python, image, pygame

How would I find the dimensions of an image I loaded into PyGame? I haven't found this in the sprite or surface classes. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images are loaded as Surface objects, so you should be able to use [Surface.get_size()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.get_size).